# i want to hide the showmore button if the height of the div(ccontainer) is less than 550px

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to hide the showmore button if the height of the div(ccontainer) is less than 550px and i will have more than one div and for each i will have a showmore button, and i already have a code that works (hides the btn) but it doesn't work for more than one button like if there are two divs it will hide the button of the first div but it just ignores the second one maybe that is because the code is implemented from top to bottom, so to sum it up what i want to do is that if div's height is less than 550px the show more button should be hidden and the code should also hide the second button for the second div.

and sorry for my broken English

**code**

js

```
// showmore btn show/hide
const btn = document.querySelector('.showmore');
const height = document.querySelector('#ccontainer').clientHeight;
btn.forEach(function(){
if (height <= 530) {btn.style.display = 'none';} else {btn.style.display = '';}
)}
```

html

```
<div class="ccontainer" id="ccontainer">
  <p id="context"> content </p>
  <div class="img" id="cntimgcon" >
    <img src="images\image2.jpg" id="cntimgp1">
</div>
<p id="context"> content </p>
</div>
<Button class="showmore"> show more </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not fully understandable.But I think you are asking that hide the top most showmore button and display other showmore button when the upper ccontainer is less than 500px.Your styling of the button looks not good to me,but I didnt change it since this is a jquery question. Inorder to test this code I duplicate  same html code you have provided. And added image url for display the image since you didnt provide image resource.And I added  `window.onload` function in order to execute your targeted function after the page loads.
[working sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/showmorebtn-11dfzw?file=/index.html).

I need to mention that you used `const btn= document.querySelector('.showmore')`.But It should be change to  `const btn =document.querySelectorAll(".showmore");`.
`querySelector` only select the first element but `querySelectorAll`  return you a list of node.

html code

```
 <div class="ccontainer" id="ccontainer">
      <p id="context">content</p>
      <div class="img" id="cntimgcon">
        <img
          src="https://crdms.images.consumerreports.org/c_lfill,w_470,q_auto,f_auto/prod/cars/chrome/white/2018TOC310001_1280_01"
          id="cntimgp1"
          height="25px"
          width="auto"
        />
      </div>

      <p id="context">content</p>
    </div>
    <button class="showmore">show more</button>
    <div class="ccontainer" id="ccontainer">
      <p id="context">content</p>
      <div class="img" id="cntimgcon">
        <img
          src="https://crdms.images.consumerreports.org/c_lfill,w_470,q_auto,f_auto/prod/cars/chrome/white/2018TOC310001_1280_01"
          id="cntimgp1"
          height="25px"
          width="auto"
        />
      </div>

      <p id="context">content</p>
    </div>
    <button class="showmore">show more</button>
```

js code

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".showmore");

      const height = document.querySelector("#ccontainer").offsetHeight;
      btn.forEach(function (single, index) {
        if (height <= 500 && index == 0) {
          single.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          single.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: @curious You don't need to give each button unique class. The answer code provided by me does the what you want. One mistake is that in your code is you didn't use document.querySelectorAll(".showmore");.This will take all showmore buttons.Then you can loop it using for each. but document. querySelector('#ccontainer') only take matching first shormore button.so that you cant loop via for each using document.querySelector('#ccontainer').

Comment: By thinking that the case,I hided upper showmore button and display other showmore button when the upper ccontainer is less than 500px) and changed the code. Since you didn't explain it clearly .It difficult to code if you can't explain it clearly.